# How to create a full-screen modal status display on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to create a modal status indicator display for an iPhone app, and would like one similar to this one used in Tweetie:

[image]

Specifically, this one "shades out" the entire screen, including the toolbar. I don't believe through any normal UIView manipulation, I can extend past the bounds of my window, can I? I believe I've seen a status indicator like this somewhere else on iPhone, possibly when I added an Exchange e-mail account.

I've tried subclassing UIAlertView and overriding its drawRect method. If I don't call [super drawRect:] it doesn't ever display the normal UIAlertView text box, however my drawing rectangle is in an odd size and position.

Anyone have any advice to accomplish this?

Comment: FWIW the Kindle iPhone app also manages to use true full screen when viewing a book's pages.

Comment: Going full screen really isn't the issue -- I can turn off the toolbar. But I leave the toolbar on in my app, and I don't want to only "shade" the rest of the screen, as it'll really make the toolbar stand out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the source code to the WordPress application.  They have code which you can basically drag and drop into your application to do this.

http://iphone.wordpress.org/development/

Comment: Where exactly in their source code did you find this?  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Check out [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but you could layer a `UIView` at the top of the view hierarchy, and use `setHidden` to dynamically show or hide it. Since it's at the top of the stack, it should be able to intercept all touch events.

Comment: I tried adding a UIView from the drawRect in my UIAlertView subclass, however it's still suffering from the weird frame dimensions.

Comment: You're adding your UIView at the wrong point. Add it as a subview of your root view controller's view and set it to Hidden.